# golang "x.509 unknown authority" on smtp, but no error on tls

Tags: email, ssl, go

When trying to send a mail with golang to my local postfix server I get the error
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Consider the following code:

```
config := &tls.Config{ServerName: "example.com"}
_, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "example.com:443", config)
//err == nil
c,_ := smtp.Dial("example.com:25")
err = c.StartTLS(config)
//err == x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Apache and postfix both use the same cert signed by StartSSL.

How comes it is accepted in one instance and rejected in the other?
As a sidenote: is it possible to get more information on the certificate in the smtp case?

Comment: have you included the intermediate cert in postfix's cert pem?

Comment: openssl's client can connect to starttls services too: `openssl s_client -connect example.com:25 -starttls smtp`

Comment: The problem is not the connection itself, but the validation of the certificate. `openssl s_client` will connect even if the certificate can not be validated but it will tell you about this in the verbose output.